# wired remote control of old equipment

Tags: remote-access, wired

I need to imagine a setup - hardware and software - to remotely use a sampler.
Like this one, for example : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akai_S3000XL

I've asked this question on the Signal processing board and a helpful comment led me to reframe it.

What needs to happen is this :

1. a student working at home has access to a website
2. the webpage is a GUI which mimics the exact controls and menu items and options available to a human working directly on a sampler
3. all the processing will be done on the sampler
4. the student will be able to save and download their work

Please point me towards any reading that would be helpful.

I would also very much appreciate any critique of the idea, because for the moment I'm not even sure what exactly I'm looking at here.

Is it just a matter of connecting a cable (several perhaps) between the sampler and a PC and reading the I/O?

Comment: It looks like the sampler can be controller over MIDI. No idea if that would give you full access to all features, though. Recording the output should be pretty trivial. Then a bit of job scheduling. But I would be you, I would probably look into software emulators doing the same thing as the hardware, it would probably give you a lot more control (including the ability for several people to use a sampler at the same time).

Comment: what will the system be sampling?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can drive this via MIDI as @jcaron suggests to get it to do what you want, you are still going to have to write a lot of code here.

Some key points

- Booking/Locking, you are going to need a way to divide up time on the device since only one student will be able to use it at once
- You will need to map all the interface options between the web page and MIDI commands
- There will be no way to change floppy disks. You also probably won't be able to access anything stored on any devices attached via the SCSI connection, unless you find a device that can emulate a SCSI endpoint

I think it would be a lot easier to look for an entirely software sampler that has an API you can build a Web front end to.